# Use index.php as main file for subfolders - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

By default my hosting provider doesn't uses the `index.php` file as the main file for the folders, so if I go to `mydomain.com/dashboard/` for example, it says that the page doesn't exist, but when I go to `mydomain.com/dashboard/index.php` it works. I'm trying to solve this with the `htaccess` file and found a solution, but it doesn't work completely. This is because I have something else in my `htaccess` to remove the `.php` extension from the url's. If I remove this part, it does work, but then I have the `.php` extension on my url again, which I don't want. This is my `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `DirectoryIndex` (part of mod_dir) - this instructs Apache which file(s) to serve when requesting a directory. (The Apache default is `index.html` inside the requested directory only.)

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This unconditionally appends the `.php` extension to any request that does not map to a file. The "problem" with this is if you request a *directory* (assuming the URL-path does not contain a dot) then it will rewrite the request to `/<directory>/.php` which will likely result in a 404.

If you are using extensionless URLs (and requesting directories directly) then you need to check that the target file exists before rewriting the request. For example:

```
# Rewrite extensionless URL to ".php" file only if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

No need to backslash-escape literal dots in regex character class. And the `NC` flag is superfluous here.

You should also make sure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise your rule is bypassed. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```